# Backing up files to remote servers

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have code that backup files to remote servers.

There are 2 pandas data frames:

- `storedfiles`: that points to the files already stored in previous runs
- `filelist`: a list of candidates to be stored in one of the depots (comes from a config file).

  Filelist structure has the following columns:

  ```
  In [10]: filelist
  Out[10]: 
                   Name     Objects    Class Subclass Creator  \  
  0  /backups/dir001/test00         400    waves     time   john      
  1  /backups/dir002/test00         400    waves     time   john      

                Created  Datahost Res  Total Size  
  0  12-Feb-15 10:10:59       NaN   D     1609728  
  1  04-Jan-15 14:40:38       NaN   D     1609728
  ```

To evaluate the storage I check the version on `filelist` against the version on `storedfiles`. If the version on file list is newer, it will be stored in some depot (the old version will be deleted). (edit) **But** to get the "version" I "need" to fetch it from a XML structure. Using an class to read the XML and process the data on it.

```
# 'a' is a instance of a internal XML processing class

# This fetchs the XML structure related to the file 'f' from filelist.
# Its a type(xmlfile) is 'str'
xmlfile = a.get_xml(f)

# This is a object to the structured data loaded on xmlfile.
# type(xmldata) is aXML
xmldata = a.load(xmlfile)

# With that I can fetch informations from my file as:
# That returns an datetime.datetime structure
type(xmldata.get_data_created())
<type 'datetime.datetime'>

# As I do at: 
version = int(xmldata.get_data_created().strftime("%s"))
```

To control versions I get the Created field (that stores a datetime) and convert it to a Unix timestamp.

My main concern is that I use too many `if`s. I feel the code is ugly and I wish have hints to do a neater and prettier code.

```
# Stored files is in fact a local csv file with this format
# It holds all file names that has being processed and stored in "depot" server
storedfiles= """
Filename,Version,Depot
foo.txt,12342412,server1
bar.mov,14144862,server2
tmp.log,13327702,server1
"""

cfcolumns=['Filename','Version','Depot']

# stdf (stored files dataframe)
# Is the dataframe that maps the local csv file with processed files
sfdf= panda.Dataframe(storedfiles,...)

# filelist is a pandas dataframe that holds a list of files to be archived
filelist = pandas.DataFrame(...)

# If there is some candidate to archive
if len(filelist.index)!=0:

    for f in filelist.filename:
        # To fetch the attributes I need to process some XML data...
        xmlfile = a.get_xml(f)
        xmldata = a.load(xmlfile)

        # Use data unix timestamp as version
        version = int(xmldata.get_data_created().strftime("%s"))

        # Get the panda series that match the 'filename' with f in loop
        # That is, look if the filename was already backuped.
        ssts = sfdf.loc[sfdf['filename'] == f]

        # Retrieves the "version"  from panda series.
        # In this case I can' t call sstv.item() on an empty series
        # Should "try/except" be used instead this? Probably yes.
        # If is the best solution, I don't know.
        sstv = ssts['Version']
        if sstv.empty:
            storedversion=0
        else:
            storedversion = sstv.item()

        # Verify if version found is newer than stored on control file
        if version > storedversion:

            # get_best_depot() returns a single hostname that can hold the file for backup
            dstdepot = get_best_depot()

            if ssts.empty:
                # data Serie is empty. Add a new entry (to be later wrote on local filesystem)

                # Stores copy the f file to the correct location on dstdepot
                if store(f,dstdepot):
                    # If successfuly stored, add to the stored files dataframe
                    sfdf=sfdf.append(pandas.DataFrame([[ f, version, dstdepot ]], columns=cfcolumns),ignore_index=True)
                else:
                    # Fails and exit.. Needs to correctly handle this
                    sys.exit(1)
            else:
                # File exists but in older version

                # Get actual depot for the file from "storedfiles"  dataFrame (sfdf)
                dstdepot = get_depot(f,sfdf)

                # Send the file to the depot server.
                if store(f,dstdepot):
                    dstidx = ssts.index[-1]
                    sfdf.loc[dstidx]=[ f,version, dstdepot ]
```

Comment: What is the `dsts` variable? You are testing against `dsts.empty` but you never set `dsts`. Is your code actually working?

Comment: @holroy I'd guess that's a typo and should be `dstdepot`, can you confirm that Lin?

Comment: It should be `ssts` instead `dsts`. ssts is the panda "sub" dataframe that contains all files  such `filename` field from storedfiles matches with `f` on for loop from `filelist.filename` (filelist cames from  a list of files candidates to the backup).

Comment: If all this variable names looks messy, is because they are messy. I'm looking for a way to write this better. Should I use snake_case variable naming instead those acronyms?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, iterating through the rows of a series or dataframe is slow, and is not the recommended process. Instead, you should do one of two things:

1. use `map` or `apply` (`map` for series, generally `apply` for data frame; see [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas) for more details)
2. select/broadcast

In this case, you have the opportunity to do both. You should use `apply` to get the version information for your `filelist` dataframe:

```
def function_that_does_your_xml_stuff(row):
    """Get version information for a row in the filelist dataframe from XML.

    Your code above sets the filename as f, but then doesn't seem to use it
    which I find confusing.  Perhaps it was a typo, and `a` should be `f`?
    Of course, a vanilla string object doesn't have a get_xml() method.

    """
    filename = row['filename']
    xmlfile = a.get_xml(filename)
    xmldata = a.load(xmlfile)
    version = int(xmldata.get_data_created().strftime("%s"))
    return version

filelist['Version'] = filelist.apply(function_that_does_your_xml_stuff, axis=1)
```

(the `axis=1` argument here tells `apply` to work on rows instead of columns).  This adds a new column to your `filelist` dataframe which contains the version information as obtained from your XML data associated with each file name.

Then, to compare with your already stored versions, you will use a selector based on your versioning criterion.  Actually, in this case, you're going to want to perform a join on the two data frames first, and then use the selector:

```
filelist = filelist.join(sfdf, how=left, on='Filename', rsuffix='_stored')
need_to_update = filelist[filelist['Version'] > filelist['Version_stored']]
need_to_update.apply(actually_update, axis=1)
```

The join here accomplishes the task of connecting the files that have already been backed up with those in `filelist`; the second line selects out only those files whose current version is greater than the one that was stored previously, and the third line actually performs the update (again, by applying a function).

Comment: `filelist` pandas.DataFrame doesn't contains `'Version'` row. It does have a `Created` row that outputs something like `12-Feb-15 10:10:59`. I try to not rely on filelist output, since it cames from another dev team (many issues involved ;-). With the filelist (and therefore with the file names). I fetch the other attributes from XML data related to that filename. Of course, I can rely on filelist structure and kick off the XML stuff. would make things simpler, but I still need to convert the `"Created"` field to something like `'version'`, already handeld on my XML lib.

Comment: I was going to respond to your comment with another comment, but I'll just edit my answer, instead.

Comment: I have enhanced the question to give a better view of the data types.

Comment: Nice idea. And yes. I haven't used `f`. Fixed that in original post. (`data` should be read as `f`).

Comment: I would say that this `apply` method is amazing. Nice hint.